# Joomla JTable ordering function runs thousands queries

Tags: joomla, jquery-jtable

When I create a new article in a category, joomla starts to reorder the whole category, even the archived articles. 
The code responsible of this is the jTable reorder function (libraries/joomla/table/table.php) which selects all the records of the same category and then, for EACH ONE, reset the ordering value with a single query.

My category contains 15k articles, 99% of them archived.

So when i save an article in that category I have to wait 15k+ queries, which takes a lot!

The question is. Why??? Have you the same problem? Any solution?

Notes:
I have Joomla 3.5, the latest one, but the problem started some versions ago.

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch on GitHub that tries to address this only for MySQL platforms, see https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/8563

Comment: Thank you, just the kind of fix I was looking for.

Comment: i had to change it a little to include mysqli and not just mysql