# 500 Internal Server Error when adding article to Jooma! 3.5 database

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla

I have a news website running Joomla! with more than 58.000 rows (articles) in `jos_content` table.

When I try to add a new article using any kind of editor, I receive a "500: Internal Server Error" and the URL link is:

```
sitename.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id=0
```

instead of

```
sitename.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id=ID_OF_THE_NEW_CREATED_ARTICLE.
```

The article is not inserted, either.

I try again by refreshing the "Internal Server Error" page, wait more than usual and, finally, the article is inserted and the link becomes

```
sitename.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id=ID_OF_THE_NEW_CREATED_ARTICLE.
```

I've tried to find the PHP that makes the `INSERT` query in the database, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla 3.x core and extensions do not handle with direct manipulation the "content" tables any more. If you dig in to the code, you'll see, that you have to use the class JTable for inserting, deleting, etc.
So, never delete or manipulate the table through mysql directly! You'll get corrupt table "assets". The class JTable take care of creating and editing the assets table in parallel with the content table.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. But why it trows me this error when adding article? Could be this related to autoincrement value of column ID from jos_content? Those about 60.000 articles where imported in the new joomla database format from a 1.5 database format. It tooked me a lot of time to do this, but I managed to do it without any errors.

Comment: How did you manage the migration from 1.5 to 3.x table? I had a similar problem, where I add some articles to the table content inside a self-made component, and within migrating to 2.5 and Joomla 3.5 I got troubles. So now I restored the assets table from the Joomla 3.5 installation and inserted each old line using the class JTable - the assets are built automatically. I spend some time, installing an eclipse IDE using the step by step debugging with xdebug. I would recommend to use this or a similar debugger to find that strange behavior.

Comment: Does it take too long storing the article? Maybe this task helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36209227/3140754

Comment: Tom, thanks a lot! That was the problem and this task stackoverflow.com/q/36209227/3140754 was the fix! I replaced the table.php with the github fix and now the articles are stored in the database immediatly. This fix sould be applied by Joomla! developers in the next release. Thanks a lot again! Topic closed...